# How to say “here and now”, I mean being present in this very moment.

Tags: kanji, phrase-requests

It is connected with buddhism, much is told about living here and now, so I guess there must be some kanji or a special phrase for describing that. Would really appreciate your help!!!

Comment: -1 for no research effort

Comment: I recommend reading some untranslated original Japanese writings on「 無の境地」 - they will contain specific phrases which are key to understanding Buddhism as it is represented through the Japanese language.

Comment: Do you mean “in the present moment” in a literal sense or more like “live in the moment” such as carpe diem? It is not clear from the question.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, 刹那{せつな} is the word. 
[Wiki:Setsuna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setsuna)

You may also want to refer to 刹那主義{せつなしゅぎ}, which is an ideology of seeking pleasure of a permanent nature, a.k.a. Epicureanism.